# Why I can't name a PyQt overloaded signal

Tags: python, pyqt

Please see the following codes.

First, I can change `self.shoot[int, int]` to `self.not_shoot[int, int]` to get the same result. This looks like to me that I have two signals, shoot and not_shoot?

Second, I can not change all 'shoot' to 'not_shoot'. This looks like that I didn't create ONE overloaded signal?

Third, I can change `self.not_shoot[int, int]` to `self.shoot[int, int]` to get the same result. This looks like I have one signal, shoot?

I can't find a good way to understand or explain this. Can anyone help me?

*See also* [Official Manual](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt5/signals_slots.html?highlight=pyqtsignal#defining-new-signals-with-pyqtsignal)

> The program result is
>
> slut int 1 2
>
> slut str strnig1 string2

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

class signalTest(QObject):

    shoot = pyqtSignal([str, str], [int, int], name='not_shoot')

    def __init__(self):

        super().__init__()
        self.not_shoot[int, int].connect(self.slut)
        self.shoot[str, str].connect(self.slut_str)
        self.shoot[int, int].emit(1, 2)
        self.shoot[str, str].emit('strnig1', 'string2')

    def slut(self, a, b):
        print('slut int', a, b )

    def slut_str(self, a, b):
        print('slut str', a, b)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    signalTest()
```

Comment: (2): this looks like it might be a bug - surely **all** the overloads should be named `not_shoot`, yet only the last one is. I suggest you report this on the [pyqt mailing list](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/mailman/listinfo/pyqt).

Comment: It's not a bug.  All you're doing is creating another reference to the same class variable (ie the `not_shoot` signal).  How is this any different than if you had done `self.another_bound_variable = self.shoot`